# Is teaching for a biology program without "specialized accreditation" bad for your career?

Tags: teaching, job-search, biology, accreditation, adjunct-faculty

I plan on graduating with my PhD in May and am currently job searching for academic positions for next fall.

I am looking into applying to be a full-time biology faculty member at a school which is accredited, but where the biology program does not have "specialized accreditation" for the field.

The question is: is it worth it?

I understand that attending a non-accredited school as a student can be detrimental to long-term success, but is the same true for *TEACHING* in a non-accredited biology program? Maybe more specifically, what are the pros and cons to working for a non-accredited program?

As a related follow-up: which would be better (or perhaps less worse) for my career as a university professor: full-time position at a poorly ranked non-accredited program or an adjunct position for a accredited program at a better-rated school?

Comment: I should preface all this by saying that I'm getting my degree from a top 15 school nationally, I'm very ambitious, and could likely get a better job at a better university (to which I am applying). But like all prudent folks before me, I am casting a wide and diverse job-searching net.

Comment: Are we talking about a program that is too new to be accredited, but likely will be shortly? Or a program that will not be accredited, possibly because it does not meet basic standards of quality?

Comment: Good question. This is a very old school with an old program. It's a liberal arts HBCU. From what I can tell, they just never strived to be a better program -- so, likely because it does not meet basic standards of quality

Comment: To clarify - the institution as a whole is accredited, but the program is not?  Is program accreditation is common or almost universal for reputable programs in your field?  (It's not universal for all fields.)

Comment: With [further inspection](http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation), the university as a whole _is_ accredited. However, their biology program is not listed as having "specialized accreditation" as a few of their other programs do. The University's website advertises these other programs front and center on their website as simply being "accredited". So University as a whole = YES, program = NO.

Comment: Decades ago, I got an engineering degree at a well known school. The department was going through re-accreditation at the time, and was getting negative feedback on some of the curriculum changes they had made. The university response was basically that they knew better than the accreditation folks, having worked closely with companies and grad schools on what needed to change,  and would be happy to move forward into the 21st century without them. (These days, engineering accreditation has changed dramatically, probably because of several such interactions).

Comment: Is accreditation even standard in biology? [This blog post](http://smallpondscience.com/2013/10/07/biology-departments-need-an-accreditation-body/) and [this article](http://www.northeastern.edu/cos/2014/01/biochemistry-accreditation/) I came across with a quick Google search suggests it isn't, but it's not my field.

Comment: I think that you need to provide some more information. What area of biology are you getting your PhD in? Are you looking to be a researcher that has teaching responsibilities or are you looking for a fully teaching faculty position? Does your area of biology have post-doctoral fellowships? If so, and you want to be in research and be a PI some day they you should be looking for a Post-Doc, preferably one where you will publish, often, before you look for a faculty position. Biology is very broad so what may be the case for certain areas of study may not be the case for others.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, very few biology programs are accredited, for example at liberal arts undergraduate colleges. But they're still important, since liberal arts students still ought to be exposed to biology. So I don't think that association with a good quality teaching program will hurt your prospects as a teacher, but unaccredited programs tend not to engage in research very intensively, if at all. So as others have mentioned, you should probably consider a post-doc at a research school if that's your goal.